# Как отсортировать данный список по возрастанию возраста студентов с помощью функций sorted и lambda?

Tags: python, list, сортировка, словари

```
students = [
        {'name': 'Mark', 'age': 18, 'course': 'java', 'gender': 'Male'},
        {'name': 'John', 'age': 15, 'course': 'python', 'gender': 'Male'},
        {'name': 'Andrew', 'age': 20, 'course': 'javascript', 'gender': 'Male'}
]
```

Comment: Покажите ваше решение этой задачи, и опишите в чем возникла проблемма?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sorted_students = sorted(students, key=lambda student: student['age'])
```

Answer (score -1):

Лично я, решил это одной строкой

```
let studentsSortedByName = students.sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
```

Comment: просто нужно решение с помощью лямбда и сорт функций

Comment: Но ведь язык вопроса - `python`